# How to add default params by using Retrofit and OKHttp in every post

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm just learning Retrofit and OKHttp, now I have an issue.
Every request in my app is POST, just like this:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("some url")
Observable<Result> getData(@Field("id") String id);
```

In every POST, there are two same params. So in a most simple way, I can add two more @Field in every method, for example, @Field("token"),@Field("account"). But I think there must be a smart way.

Then I thought OkHttpClient may solve this.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();
            RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder().add("account", "me")
                    .add("token", "123456").build();
            request = request.newBuilder().post(body).build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    }).build();
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("some base url")
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

Or

```
HttpUrl url = request.url().newBuilder()
                    .setEncodedQueryParameter("account", "me")
                    .setEncodedQueryParameter("token", "123456")
                    .build();
```

The first method just replace all Field to these two.

The second method just add these two as GET parameters, not POST.

Now I have absolutely no idea how to make this work.

Answer (score 3):

OK...Finally I find a way to do this. But I'm not sure this is the best way.

Here is the code:

```
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();
            FormBody.Builder bodyBuilder = new FormBody.Builder();
            FormBody b = (FormBody) request.body();
            for (int i=0;i<b.size();i++) {
                bodyBuilder.addEncoded(b.name(i),b.value(i));
            }
            bodyBuilder.addEncoded("account", "me").add("token", "123456");
            request = request.newBuilder().post(bodyBuilder.build()).build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    }).build();
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://some url)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

I get all the @Field from retrofit, then add every key-value params to a new RequestBody, same as these two default params. Now every POST request has "account" and "token".

If there is a better way to do this, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by adding a new request interceptor to the OkHttpClient. Intercept the actual request and get the HttpUrl. The http url is required to add query parameters since it will change the previously generated request url by appending the query parameter name and its value.

```
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient =  
    new OkHttpClient.Builder();
httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {  
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request original = chain.request();
        HttpUrl originalHttpUrl = original.url();

        HttpUrl url = originalHttpUrl.newBuilder()
                .addQueryParameter("apikey", "your-actual-api-key")
                .build();

        // Request customization: add request headers
        Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                .url(url);

        Request request = requestBuilder.build();
        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
});
```